# Turing machine to convert base-9 number to base-3 in O(log(n))

Tags: algorithms

Greetings, dear Mathematicians!

How to implement base-9 to base-3 conversion in O(log(n)) on 4-tuple ((stateFrom, encounterWhat, Command, StateTo), where Command can be < (turn left), > (turn right), # (stop execution), or symbol from an alphabet) Turing machine, finite from the left side and infinite from the right side?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: (1) Looks like an exercise in a book.  If this is the case, it is better to state the source.  (2) What is n?  (Well, I know what n is but you should make it clear in the question.)

Comment: There's a bit of overlap into math, but I suspect this question might be even more interesting to the folks over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Have you tried asking there yet?

Answer (score 1):

What is n here?
Is it no .of digits or the value of the number?

If it is the value of the no,, then just convert each digit of base-9 no. in to its base-3 equivalent.